# passing select query from stored procedure into a ArrayList in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, arraylist, parameters

I have a stored procedure that select data and it gives me 8 rows and 4 columns of data. I wanted to know how will i be able to pass these data to an array list in c#?

I am using MS SQL.

Comment: Which DBMS / ORM are you on?

Comment: hi i am using mssql server

Comment: Then you can user EF: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/stored-procedure-in-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: As the [ArrayList documentation itself says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=netframework-4.8) - _"**We don't recommend that you use the ArrayList class for new development**. Instead, we recommend that you use the generic List<T> class. The ArrayList class is designed to hold heterogeneous collections of objects. However, it does not always offer the best performance._

Answer (score 0):

I suggeste you to create a class, for example, you are using table Student, this student has (id, name, age, phone : 4 columns), create a Student class with 4 properties, and at the moment of receiving data from DB, using a loop, create instance from student class and save in it a single row of data, and add it to the arrayList.
or use anonymous type in c# instead of student class